# In Skyrim, can you play past the game's final quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Bethesda games, sadly, have been going downhill with respect to playing past the ending quest:

- In Oblivion, you could play past the game's ending and even got a special piece of armor from it.
- In Fallout 3, you couldn't play past the ending without buying the Broken Steel DLC.
- In Fallout: New Vegas, you couldn't play past the ending. Period.

How does Skyrim handle the ending mission in this respect?

Comment: To be fair, Bethesda didn't develop New Vegas. Also, I love your avatar.

Comment: I stumbled across an interview saying that you can progress past the ending without buying DLC. If I can find it again, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot To be absolutely fair, yes, that should be noted. Also, thank you :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Quoting developer Todd Howard:

> "When you finish the main quest you’ll be able to continue playing.”

And in reponse to if Skyrim's ending will be like Fallout 3, where you had to buy DLC:

> "No, that was a mistake."

Source:
[Relevent Text](http://www.randomprodinc.com/todd-howard-discusses-skyrim-quests-and-dlc/)
[Full video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9R33th33SA&list=FLPnTYT2EJUJaPZ9X1hdEMIA&index=14)

Comment: Excellent! Let's hope they do this with all future games, eh? :D