# Can I continue to play after the game ends?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Two quick questions about skyrim:

1. Can I continue to play after I've completed the main quest? I'm pretty sure that's a yes.
2. Will something significant have changed after the main quest is done, so that I should do my exploring first? Like in Oblivion where a city was destroyed pretty early and then the gates appeared all over making things more difficult.

Comment: I would focus on the second question, the first is already answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35165/in-skyrim-can-you-play-past-the-games-final-quest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Yes you can, you can continue playing and complete all the side quests.
2. There are no really significant changes like in Oblivion. For example even the dragons will still be around for you to hunt down. Without giving to much away, one of the small things that change is that NPCs will sometimes comment on your achievements during the main quest.

Comment: There is no such thing as "all the side quests" in Skyrim. Radiant / Miscellaneous quests randomly generate forever.

Comment: And indeed, [dragons stay around](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35544/do-dragons-respawn/35551#35551)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, there are many quests to do outside of the main quest line and don't worry te game is still just as fun, to be honest some of the other quest lines seemed as good or better than the main game.

Answer (score 1):

1.Yes you can.
 .If you're bored, just start collecting all the dragon priests and do quests for the daedric lords.

No worries, no change

Answer (score -2):

Yes it continues, missions are still available but be warned at certain points in the game some characters may become unavailable for side quests. Some characters will have new quests available further into the game so I’d recommend using the comprehensive walkthrough on TrueAchievements.com which gives you a brief summary of what quests to do in what order which should prevent any mission skips. Be warned also once the dragons spawn after whiterun they may kill npc’s that provide missions etc so this can cause irreversible consequences. Be sure to keep 2-3 save states and save consistently. Turn off auto save if you are doing this. :)

Comment: This thread is soooo old xD

Comment: [This answer is not contributing anything new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313578/should-i-downvote-an-answer-no-added-value-posted-on-an-already-well-answered) to a question that has been answered eight years ago